# Unexpected whitespace between function name and paren.(func-call-spacing), A space is required before '}'.(object-curly-spacing), webstorm quasar vue

Tags: vue.js, formatting, webstorm, spacing, quasar

I'm new to using stackoverflow and using WebStorm quasar,and vuejs, so let me know if you need any more details or if I did something wrong.

pictures of code errors:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13oSjnK6Q21ztsihbcF0a-TUUAWAo0vcW?usp=sharing

errors:

ESLint: A space is required after '{'.(object-curly-spacing)
enter image description here
ESLint: Unexpected whitespace between function name and paren.(func-call-spacing)

I correct these errors by adding the correct spacing, but whenever I refresh the website, I'm working on, WebStorm changes them back.

I believe its some sort of a formatting error.
I've gone into,

Settings->Editor->Code Style -> JavaScript
Settings->Editor->Code Style -> TypeScript

and clicked on spaces, and check the appropriate boxes.
spaces - before parenthesis - function call parenthesis
spaces - within - object literal braces

but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my nuxt project when using typescript on a `defineEmit` API. It solved by adding `"func-call-spacing": "off"` on your `.eslintrc` file.

Some helpful link
https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/func-call-spacing/#how-to-use

[image]

```js
"rules": {
  "func-call-spacing": "off"
}
```

When it is off
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have disabled the **Spaces > Before parentheses > Function call parentheses** and enabled the **Within > ES6 Import/Export Braces** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript**; please also make sure that you don't have the IDE code style preferences overwritten by the settings in project `.editorconfig` (if any)